# Excel- Count duplicate values in multiple columns using pivot table

Tags: excel

I am  trying to create a pivot table with rows having count of duplicates from multiple columns.

e.g.:

my current record is in below format:

[image: my current record is in below format]

Output in a pivot table should be:

[image: Output in a pivot table should be]

Please help with the option.

Excel formula can also work.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, try first. Stack Overflow is not free code writing service.

Comment: You may have to add an extra column to your data source which counts the duplicates, then recreate the pivot table with that as your new value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pivot tables to do this. You should create a separate column of your values as a new column, remove duplicates and then assuming that your reference column is column D of that sheet (which you will generate by removing duplicates of column B and c), you can apply this formula beginning from E1 to count each item :  =COUNTIF(B1:C7,D1), when you drag the formula down below until your last entry, you should get the number of each item. This is how your table should look like after applying your formula:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCTj7.jpg

```
A    B       C        D     E
--   --      --      ---   ---
AAA 2666    2666    2666    5 (Formula:  =COUNTIF(B1:C7,D1))
BBB 9953    1171    9953    3
CCC 2666    1171    1171    4
DDD 9953    9953    1252    1
EEE 1171    1171        
FFF 2666    2666        
GGG 1252    1171
```

If your solution requires that it must use a pivot table, I don't have any on idea how to that though. But I think you should again aggregate your data ( perhaps by adding your columns side by side to create a new column) and then apply a pivot table selecting the final column as "rows" and their values as "count row X". Something along these lines:

You should aggregate your data this way;

```
2666
9953
2666
9953
1171
2666
1252
2666
1171
1171
9953
1171
2666
1171
```

and your pivot table fields (while you are generating it) should look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzkbu.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a PivotTable if you unpivot the data first. You can either use PowerQuery to do this (if you have Excel 2013 or later) or you can use VBA. Search Google for the terms "Excel" and "Unpivot" and you'll turn up lots of ways of doing this, including some VBA code I wrote [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/), and a non-VBA approach [here](http://www.contextures.com/excelpivottablesourcedatafix.html).